# how to multiply all the numbers in a sequence (python)

Tags: python, numbers, sequence

Like if i told the program `n=10`, how would I make it return `10*9*8*7*6*5....1`?

I thought a while loop but I feel I messed up somewhere because it doesn't sum up all of the numbers in the sequence.

My current code looks like this

```
def product(n):
  i=n
  a=n-1
  while a>0:
    return i * a
    b=i * a
    a=a-1
    i=i-1
```

Are there any better ways to do it without using recursion? Sorry for the incredibly beginner question, but I'm trying to teach myself how to code. You gotta start somewhere!

Thanks!

Comment: Sum or multiply? PS you're `return`ing first thing in your loop...

Comment: multiply,how do i make it return everything?

Comment: When you `return` you're not letting any of the rest of the loop code run, and you're only looping once.

Comment: so, putting the return value outside of the loop should solve this? I'm confused about how the while loop is to multiply all of the numbers. Like I feel with my current code, every time it loops its going to reset the value, if that makes any sense.

Comment: You could use `reduce` if you like, but if the goal is to learn that's probably not so good. `reduce(range(1, n+1), lambda a, b: a*b)` Or `math.factorial`

Comment: @BillyThompson When you hit `return`, you exit the current function, so if you want your loop to go around more than once, the return has to be outside of the loop. You'll want it after the loop after all the work has been done, so that you can use it to return a value.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure - nothing wrong with learning about `reduce`, although you have your args reversed, the function comes first, the sequence second. This makes it easy to combine `reduce` and a lambda into a function that just takes sequences, by using `functools.partial`, such as `product_of = partial(reduce, lambda a,b: a*b)` making it easy to write `print product_of(range(1,10+1))`.

Comment: Bah. Sorry, it's been a while since I've used reduce, but now I know you're right.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are trying to learn to code, I won't give you a total solution, but 
I'll give you a few hints instead:

- Have a `for` loop that runs up from 1 to n (using `range(1, n+1)`) instead of your `while`-loop. This will generate the values that you want to multiply and iterate the right number of times (which can be a bit tricky with `while` loops sometimes).
- Have a variable named `product` to store the result of the multiplications each time through the loop.
- Initialize `product` before you enter the `for`-loop. Once inside you'll be just updating the value of `product`.
- After you are done with the loop, you can use the `return` statement to return the value of `product`.
- Finally, for testing purposes, you may want to start out with a small value of `n`, like 4, and print out the values you are computing inside the loop to verify how your code is working.

There are more terse and pythonic ways to do this, but this uses the code structure you have already set up. And of course recursively as well as you mention too.

Once you master the basics, you'll appreciate the more idiomatic ways of writing this, or calling the appropriate functions that do this for you.

Comment: @BillyThompson good .. let me know if you have any questions/how it goes, I think this is more useful in the long-term than seeing how to call functions, or getting an already written solution.

Comment: Ok will do :) Exactly, I want to be able to understand the method behind the madness before moving calling functions.

Answer (score 4):

Well, here's another Pythonic approach.

```
>>> import operator
>>> numbers = range(1, 11)
>>> numbers
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> reduce(operator.mul, numbers)
3628800
```

Comment: Yes, but how does that help OP learn to program? OP states "I'm trying to teach myself how to code". This shows how to call functions ...

Comment: This directly answers the question stated in the title. "how to multiply all the numbers in a sequence"

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't just for the OP, it's also for people who land here from e.g. a Google search.

Comment: I agree with you, SO isn't just for OP, but *this* question *is*. Based on OP's posts, I doubt seeing `reduce()` etc is going to help OP. I guess everyone tries to help in their own way.

Comment: I think this is the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you what you meant is factorial function, you can simply just use the `math.factorial()`:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.factorial(10)
3628800
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to understanding the logic behind the factorial aspect of it. This will come in handy though.

Comment: I don't think this helps OP learn how to program, but rather how to call functions.

Comment: My answer included `math.factorial` as well as an attempt to show him how to implement it on his own :-p

Comment: @Levon Sorry, I disagree. I believe "how to call the right functions" rather than implementing everything from scratch, is an important part of learning how to program too. Learning how to make this kind of judgement is even more important. Furthermore, the OP asked clearly if there's an easier way to do it "without recursion", and there is. Given these reasons, I don't see how my answer deserves a downvote.

Comment: I haven't downvoted a *single* answer here .. just because I make comments doesn't imply that .. so please don't jump to conclusions. Perhaps others find your approach not helpful? At least one other person must. And you are not helping OP learn how to program, but use the product of other programmers.

Comment: @Levon Sorry about the implication that the downvote was from you. I am not trying to get into an arguement here, but don't you think learning how to use the product of other programmers is also "learning how to program"? Even Python itself is a "product" of other programmers. Unless you are talking strictly about learning algorithms.

Comment: Of course it's good (and smart) to use functions (code reuse and all), but if you are just starting out to learn to program (as OP is), you should learn the basics. Honestly, one can't think that OP has a better grasp of programming after calling the factorial function. Yes, OP will have a solution, but not more *understanding* than before. OP states their desire to learn. Let's agree to disagree (and there's no bad feeling or desire for argument on my side).

Comment: @Levon I guess the fundamental difference is your opinion of what a beginner should learn. I simply believe they should learn *both* the proper way to do things, and the algorithm behind it. So I welcome your solution and time, and I would like this discussion to end here :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to find the factorial of a number n, essentially. For finding the factorial of a number, there are 2 methods

1. Using a Loop structure
2. Using Recursion (as you've mentioned)

As a new programmer, you would be better off with a simple loop structure that runs from 1 to n and puts the multiplied value at each iteration into a variable. That variable is your answer. But also know that recursion will also work and make the code look elegant. Happy Programming !

Answer (score 1):

This is called the *factorial*. *10!* is equivalent to *10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1*.

```
def factorial(n):
    product = 1
    while n > 0:
        product *= n
        n -= 1
    return product
```

By the way, in practice, just use [`math.factorial`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.factorial).

Comment: Woah, thanks so much. But, I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding it. What does the *= n do? I'm assuming that it allows n to be multiplied by n-1? But, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it because why does n store itself as n*(n-1) every time it loops. Sorry, its hard for me to put into words why it confuses me.

Comment: @BillyThompson `product *= n` means `product = product * n`; it multiplies the product so far for each `n` until it reaches `0`. `n -= 1` is the same as `n = n - 1`, subtracting `1` each loop.

Comment: @BillyThompson essentially, it counts down from `n` to `0`, storing the result of their cumulative product in `product`.

Comment: Thank you, that kind of helps to put it in perspective to me. I just haven't been introduced to that syntax yet. I'm going to try and fully grasp and apply it right now.

Comment: The compound assignment operators are just shorthand... don't feel stressed :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 def factorial(n):
     if n <= 1: return 1
     return n * factorial(n-1)
```

I always think of factorial as the quintessential example in learning recursion ...

Comment: Yeah, but I'm just trying to get a grasp on how to do it iteratively before I move onto recursion. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Try to compute `factorial(1000)` with this approach. :^)

Comment: yeah I know that wont work :P ... I usually did this exercise in C land which still had its issues but less so than python for this problem

Comment: @JoranBeasley: trying the same thing in C will be even worse, you probably won't even be able to compute factorial(25).  As you know perfectly well. :-)

Comment: Your code will return `factorial(-10) == 1` as `True`, while factorial of negative numbers is undefined. Minor issue, but still.

Comment: Factorial is so clearly implemented using iteration over recursion, I think it is the quintessential example of contorting a problem to a particular programming topic.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire yes correct implementation is iterative(I +1'd your comment)...however it is also one of the easiest functions to implement recursively and therefore provides a gentle introduction to recursion, at least imho

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use `scipy.product`.

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.product(xrange(1,11))
3628800
```

Answer (score 0):

As a learner you should do it without using any inbuilt functions it will help you to learn programming rather just tool as learning a tool is much easier one you become good programmer. there are two ways of doing this I have implemented simpler versions.

Using Recursion:

```
def product(n):
    if n== 1:
        return 1
    return n * product(n-1)
```

Using Simple Loop:

```
def product(n):
    res = 1
    while n>1:
        res = res * n
        n = n - 1
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

For factorials too large to compute directly, there is another way to do that by using the Stirling's approximation.

n! := sqrt(2πn)*(n/e)^n, where e = 2.71828